# Network uses UUID for authendication instead of MAC

Tags: authentication, networking, uuid, fedora, mac-address

I use fedora 21 for legacy reason and try to connect to the ethernet which uses the MAC address for auth. But the "if" alsways trys to authenticate with a UUID.
I tried to remove the UUID from the ifcfg file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ but it always comes back after restarting the network. How can I change this behaviour and use MAC instead?

Comment: Using MAC addresses for authentication is pretty foolish. It is far too easy to change a MAC address on a device.

Comment: Might be but not my choice nor the problem.